# Spring Boot Redirecting to another controller method from current controller method

Tags: spring-boot

Hi all am new to spring boot. Am stuck in the middle of my learning path. I have two controllers(@Controller) with some methods define in them. Am submitting form data to a method in index controller and wants to move to the method in home controller if form submission gets successful(on succesfull login). while loading `http://localhost:9090/`method of index controller it loads all the static content correctly, but when i redirect`return "redirect:/dashboard/index"` then it navigates to `http://localhost:9090/dashBoard/index`. And `/dashboard/index` method is as follow

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/dashBoard/index")
    public String hello(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

this method return "index" which is `.jsp` page but redirecting to this method changes static content path like `http://localhost:9090/dashBoard/assets/images/avatar/1.jpg`

it seems like appending `/dashBoard/` in path of static content. Am not understanding what to do please help. Am adding my project properties and structure please have a look

`application.properties`

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.resources.static-locations=file:/var/www/static,classpath:static
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
server.port=9090
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
```

`main class`

```
[@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SchoolpageApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String\[\] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchoolpageApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(SchoolpageApplication.class);
    }
}
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Y9G.png)

[Static content path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynwzG.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dashBoard")
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("index")
    public String hello(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

You could try this method, everytime you get throught an url with /dashboard you will get inside this controller, and you can control every option you want with the next income like /foo (in this case /index) and in the return it will get you into /dashboard/+your return value(in this case index).

I´m not an expert with spring boot, I´m pretty new with it too but I hope this can help you.

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer, but your idea doesnt work. I have already tried this way but it didnt helped. I solved it by somehow by shortening requestmapping value from "dashBoard/index" to "/index" and all static contents loaded correctly.